# css 3 divs positioning, one with overflow: scroll

Tags: css

If you look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kamilszokaluk/uhmYg/
I have 3 divs, the upper one is supposed to be on top on the page and lower at the bottom of the visible part (with no scrolling). They're not moving, so my first thought was to set their position: fixed with top: 0 for first and bottom: 0 for second. But my goal is that the only div that scrolls is the "content" div, when I set position mentioned above, the whole page is scrollable. The intended layout is like this:

```
 _________________         __
|                 |          |
|       upper     |          |
|_________________|          |
|                ||          |
|   content with ||          |
|   scroll       ||          |---your browser window
|                ||          |
|________________||          |
|                 |          |
|    lower        |          |
|_________________|        __|
```

Is it possible to ignore the height of "content", cause it changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is that you can't just set a fixed height on `.content` because you want it to fill whatever remaining middle space there is automatically?

In which case you will need to either use percentage heights or my preferred approach would be to have the content div stretch from under the upper div to the bottom of the page with a negative margin equal to the height of the bottom div.

Or just absolute position the middle div like: http://jsfiddle.net/uhmYg/9/

Edit: added absolute example

Answer (score 0):

set a fixed height for the `.content` and then add `overflow-y:scroll;`

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/uhmYg/4/

Comment: the problem is that different people have different resolution... only solution I see is jquery?

Comment: @kamil yes jQuery could be a solution find the height of the window and then set a dynamic height for `.content`